# wordpress reader declangao and navigation drawer

Tags: android

I'm new in android programmation. I'm triyng to implement a navigation drawer in wordpress reader declan gao project. I'm getting crazy. He loads a list of wordpress posts and display it with cardview. If I put all necessary in activity_main My navigation drawer appears below cardview posts and I can't interact with it. If I try to put it in TabLayoutFragment i have a lot of errors!!!

Is there someone who can help me to insert navigation drawer in the right place!!!

**Than you so much!!!**

This is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    RecyclerViewFragment.PostListListener, PostFragment.PostListener,
    TabLayoutFragment.TabLayoutListener,       SearchResultFragment.SearchResultListener
    {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String TAB_LAYOUT_FRAGMENT_TAG = "TabLayoutFragment";
public static final String POST_FRAGMENT_TAG = "PostFragment";


private FragmentManager fm = null;
private TabLayoutFragment tlf;
private PostFragment pf;

private SearchResultFragment srf;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Setup fragments
    tlf = new TabLayoutFragment();
    pf = new PostFragment();
    srf = new SearchResultFragment();

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, pf, POST_FRAGMENT_TAG);

    ft.add(android.R.id.content, tlf, TAB_LAYOUT_FRAGMENT_TAG);

    ft.hide(pf);

    ft.commit();
}

/**
 * Invoked when a post in the list is selected
 *
 * @param post Selected Post object
 */
@Override
public void onPostSelected(Post post, boolean isSearch) {
    // Find the fragment in order to set it up later
    pf = (PostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(POST_FRAGMENT_TAG);

    // Set necessary arguments
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("id", post.getId());
    args.putString("title", post.getTitle());
    args.putString("date", post.getDate());
    args.putString("author", post.getAuthor());
    args.putString("content", post.getContent());
    args.putString("url", post.getUrl());
    //args.putString("thumbnailUrl", post.getThumbnailUrl());
    args.putString("featuredImage", post.getFeaturedImageUrl());

    // Configure PostFragment to display the right post
    pf.setUIArguments(args);

    // Show the fragment
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right,
            android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    if (!isSearch) { // Hide TabLayoutFragment if this is not search result
        ft.hide(tlf);
    } else { // Otherwise, hide the search result, ie. SearchResultFragment.
        ft.hide(srf);
    }
    ft.show(pf);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}

/**
 * Invoked when a search query is submitted
 *
 * @param query Selected Post object
 */
@Override
public void onSearchSubmitted(String query) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right,
            android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    // Send query to fragment using factory method
    srf = SearchResultFragment.newInstance(query);
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, srf);
    ft.hide(tlf);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}

/**
 * Invoked when comment menu is selected
 *
 * @param id ID of the article, assigned by WordPress
 */
@Override
public void onCommentSelected(int id) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("id", id);
    // Setup CommentFragment to display the right comments page


    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right,
            android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    ft.hide(pf);

    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}

/**
 * Intercept back button event, reset ActionBar if necessary
 */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    resetActionBarIfApplicable();
    super.onBackPressed();
}

/**
 * Simulate a back button press when home is selected
 */
@Override
public void onHomePressed() {
    resetActionBarIfApplicable();
    fm.popBackStack();
}

/**
 * Reset TabLayoutFragment's ActionBar if necessary
 */
private void resetActionBarIfApplicable() {
    Log.d(TAG, "SearchResultFragment is visible: " + srf.isHidden());
    if (srf.isVisible()) {
        tlf.resetActionBar();
    }
}

// Commented out coz we will let fragments handle their own Options Menus
//@Override
//public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
//    return true;
//}
```

}

This is activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:background="@color/colorPrimary"-->
    <!--android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/toolbar">-->
<!--</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>-->

<!--<FrameLayout-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/container"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent">-->
<!--</FrameLayout>-->
```

This is TabLayoutFragment.java

```
  /**
    * Fragment to display TabLayout and ViewPager.
    * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
    * {@link TabLayoutFragment.TabLayoutListener} interface
    * to handle interaction events.
   */
    public class TabLayoutFragment extends Fragment implements      SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
private static final String TAG = "TabLayoutFragment";

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private SearchView searchView;
private MenuItem searchMenuItem;

// List of all categories
protected static ArrayList<Category> categories = null;

private TabLayoutListener mListener;

public TabLayoutFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Stops onDestroy() and onCreate() being called when the parent
    // activity is destroyed/recreated on configuration change
    setRetainInstance(true);

    // Display a search menu
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_layout, container, false);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    // Preload 1 page to either side of the current page
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    loadCategories();
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu()");

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // Create expandable & collapsible SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)
            getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Expanded by default
    //searchView.requestFocus();
    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_hint));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_search) {
        searchView.requestFocus();
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Reset the ActionBar to show proper menu and collapse SearchView
 */
protected void resetActionBar() {
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
}

/**
 * Download categories and create tabs
 */
private void loadCategories() {
    // Display a progress dialog
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading_categories));
    // User cannot dismiss it by touching outside the dialog
    mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();

    // Make a request to get categories
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Config.CATEGORY_URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                // Request succeeded
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                    // Get categories from JSON data
                    categories = JSONParser.parseCategories(jsonObject);

                    RecyclerViewFragmentPagerAdaptor adaptor = new
                            RecyclerViewFragmentPagerAdaptor(getChildFragmentManager(), categories);
                    mViewPager.setAdapter(adaptor);
                    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
                }
            },
            // Request failed
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "----- Volley Error -----");
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    // Show an INDEFINITE Snackbar. New in design support lib v22.2.1.
                    Snackbar.make(mTabLayout, R.string.error_load_categories,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction(R.string.action_retry,
                            new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    loadCategories();
                                }
                            }).show();
                }
            });
    // Add the request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    searchView.clearFocus(); // Hide soft keyboard
    mListener.onSearchSubmitted(query); // Deal with fragment transaction on MainActivity
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mListener = (TabLayoutListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() +
                "must implement PostListListener");
    }
}

// Interface used to communicate with MainActivity
public interface TabLayoutListener {
    void onSearchSubmitted(String query);
}
```

}
This is FragmentTabLayout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="me.declangao.wordpressreader.app.TabLayoutFragment">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        style="@style/CustomTabLayout"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is RecyclerViewFragment.java

```
  /**
    * Fragment to display a RecyclerView.
    * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
    * {@link RecyclerViewFragment.PostListListener} interface
    * to handle interaction events.
   */
   public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment implements  SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewFragment";
protected static final String CAT_ID = "id";
protected static final String QUERY = "query";

private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MyRecyclerViewAdaptor mAdaptor;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
// Widget to show user a loading message
private TextView mLoadingView;

// List of all posts in the ListView
private ArrayList<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();
// A flag to keep track if the app is currently loading new posts
private boolean isLoading = false;

private int mPage = 1; // Page number
private int mCatId; // Category ID
private int mPreviousPostNum = 0; // Number of posts in the list
private int mPostNum; // Number of posts in the "new" list
private String mQuery = ""; // Query string used for search result
// Flag to determine if current fragment is used to show search result
private boolean isSearch = false;

// Keep track of the list items
private int mPastVisibleItems;
private int mVisibleItemCount;

private PostListListener mListener;

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param id ID of the category.
 * @return A new instance of RecyclerViewFragment.
 */
public static RecyclerViewFragment newInstance(int id) {
    RecyclerViewFragment fragment = new RecyclerViewFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(CAT_ID, id);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of this fragment
 * using the provided parameters to display search result.
 *
 * @param query search query.
 * @return A new instance of RecyclerViewFragment.
 */
public static RecyclerViewFragment newInstance(String query) {
    RecyclerViewFragment fragment = new RecyclerViewFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(QUERY, query);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public RecyclerViewFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mCatId = getArguments().getInt(CAT_ID, -1);
        mQuery = getArguments().getString(QUERY, "");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_view, container, false);

    // Pull to refresh layout
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mLoadingView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_loading);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    // Pull to refresh listener
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    // RecyclerView adaptor for Post object
    mAdaptor = new MyRecyclerViewAdaptor(postList, new MyRecyclerViewAdaptor.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Post post) {
            mListener.onPostSelected(post, isSearch);
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); // Every row in the list has the same size
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaptor);
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        // Automatically load new posts if end of the list is reached
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            //super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            mVisibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            mPastVisibleItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();

            if (mPostNum > mPreviousPostNum && !postList.isEmpty() && mVisibleItemCount != 0 &&
                    totalItemCount > mVisibleItemCount && !isLoading &&
                    (mVisibleItemCount + mPastVisibleItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                loadNextPage();
                // Update post number
                mPreviousPostNum = mPostNum;
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    loadFirstPage();
}

/**
 * Load the first page of a category
 */
public void loadFirstPage(){
    mPage = 1; // Reset page number

    if (postList.isEmpty()) {
        showLoadingView();
        // Reset post number to 0
        mPreviousPostNum = 0;
        loadPosts(mPage, false);
    } else {
        hideLoadingView();
    }
}

/**
 * Load the next page of a category
 */
public void loadNextPage(){
    mPage ++;
    loadPosts(mPage, true);
}

/**
 * Load posts from a specific page number
 *
 * @param page Page number
 * @param showLoadingMsg Flag to determine whether to show Toast loading msg to inform the user
 */
private void loadPosts(int page, final boolean showLoadingMsg) {
    Log.d(TAG, "----------------- Loading category id " + mCatId +
            ", page " + String.valueOf(page));

    isLoading = true;

    if (showLoadingMsg) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.loading_articles),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Construct the proper API Url
    String url;
    if (!mQuery.isEmpty()) { // Not empty mQuery means this list is for search result.
        isSearch = true;
        url = Config.BASE_URL + "?json=get_search_results&search=" + mQuery +
                "&page=" + String.valueOf(page);
    } else { // Empty mQuery means normal list of posts
        isSearch = false;

        if (mCatId == 0) { // The "All" tab
            url = Config.BASE_URL + "?json=get_posts&page=" + String.valueOf(page);
        } else { // Everything else
            isSearch = false;
            url = Config.BASE_URL + "?json=get_category_posts&category_id=" + String.valueOf(mCatId)
                    + "&page=" + String.valueOf(page);
        }

    }

    Log.d(TAG, url);
    // Request post JSON
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); // Stop when done

                    // Parse JSON data
                    postList.addAll(JSONParser.parsePosts(jsonObject));

                    // A temporary workaround to avoid downloading duplicate posts in some
                    // rare circumstances by converting ArrayList to a LinkedHashSet without
                    // losing its order
                    Set<Post> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(postList);
                    postList.clear();
                    postList.addAll(new ArrayList<>(set));

                    mPostNum = postList.size(); // The newest post number
                    Log.d(TAG, "Number of posts: " + mPostNum);
                    mAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Display the list

                    // Set ListView position
                    if (RecyclerViewFragment.this.mPage != 1) {
                        // Move the article list up by one row
                        // We don't actually need to add 1 here since position starts at 0
                        mLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(mPastVisibleItems + mVisibleItemCount);
                    }

                    // Loading finished. Set flag to false
                    isLoading = false;

                    hideLoadingView();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    isLoading = false;
                    hideLoadingView();
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                    volleyError.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, "----- Error: " + volleyError.getMessage());

                    // Show a Snackbar with a retry button
                    Snackbar.make(mRecyclerView, R.string.error_load_posts,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction(R.string.action_retry,
                            new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    //loadFirstPage();
                                    loadPosts(mPage, true);
                                }
                            }).show();
                }
            });

    // Set timeout to 10 seconds instead of the default value 5 since my
    // crappy server is quite slow
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    // Add request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request, TAG);
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    // Clear the list
    postList.clear();
    mAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    loadFirstPage();
}

/**
 * Show the loading view and hide the list
 */
private void showLoadingView() {
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mLoadingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

/**
 * Hide the loading view and show the list
 */
private void hideLoadingView() {
    mLoadingView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mListener = (PostListListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() +
                "must implement PostListListener");
    }
}

// Interface used to communicate with MainActivity
public interface PostListListener {
    void onPostSelected(Post post, boolean isSearch);
}
```

}

This is fragment_recyclerview.xml

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context="me.declangao.wordpressreader.app.RecyclerViewFragment">

<!-- Article list -->
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/text_view_loading"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/loading_articles"/>
```

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem ?

Comment: can you share how you put drawer in the declangao project ..?